# Javascript ajax call get access is denied error in IE11

Tags: jquery, ajax, amazon-web-services, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am using the below code to try to upload files to AWS S3 server:

```
  function ajaxUpload(fd, file, signedFormData, nameOfFile) {
      var IsCompletedFired = 0;

      $.support.cors = true;
      var jqXHR=$.ajax({

          xhr: function() {   

              //...
          },
          url: "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/"+signedFormData.bucket +"/",
          type: "POST",
          crossDomain: true,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          cache: false,
          async: true,
          dataType: false,
          enctype:"multipart/form-data",
          encoding:"multipart/form-data",
          data: fd,
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log('xhr'+ xhr);
              console.log('textStatus'+ textStatus);
              console.log('errorThrown '+errorThrown);
          },
          success: function(data){

          }(signedFormData) // end of success callback
      });  // end of AJAX*/
      uploadAjaxCalls[uploadAjaxCalls.length] = jqXHR;
  }
```

This works in Chrome, firefox and Edge. But doesn't work for IE11. I haven't tried any IE versions lower than 11. I have googled about this issue and tried everything I could but none of them worked for me.

So things I have tried include:

1. Put 1 millisecond before running the ajax call. I have used the below code to call the method:

   setTimeout( function() {
          ajaxUpload(fd, file, signedFormData, nameOfFile);
     },1);
2. Add AWS S3 website and the caller's website into IE's trusted sites list.
3. Add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` into the web page.

But currently none of them worked for me yet. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Is there any error you see in the IE console?

Comment: @KhalidT. Yes, access is denied. It is not an error actually, but the console.log() part of the error section.

Comment: Although it works in Chrome, do you see any warning in Chrome's console? Have you tried `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`? What's the jQuery version you're currently using?

Comment: @KhalidT. There is no localhost in my code. I am not quite sure which version of jquery it is. It is just the legacy one which we have been using for a while.

Comment: have you set `xhr.timeout` anywhere? While not allowed before `xhr.open` for longer, only now IE seems to abort the call altogether.